# Tkinter chatbot insert text design

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, text, chatbot

I'm designing a chatbot in the initial phase. I need help with something. I created a text window in the Tkinter module. I want the window to be written from the bottom upwards. I also want to make the background to the text in the window.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.font import Font
root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
root.title('deneme')
root.geometry('410x600+400+100')
root.config(bg='lightblue')

giriş = Entry(root, font=('NanumGothic', 12))
giriş.pack()
giriş.place(x=10, y=550, width=290, height=40)

buton = Button(root, width=10, height=2)
buton.pack()
buton.place(x=310, y=550)
buton.config(text='GÖNDER', bg='lightblue', font='Verdana 8 bold')

asd = Text(root, bg='red', fg='white')
asd = ('deneme')


pencere = Text(root, yscrollcommand='YES', font=('NanumGothic', 12))
pencere.pack()
pencere.place(x=10, y=10, width=390, height=530)
pencere.insert('end','\nBOT:\t' + asd)  # bot karşılama mesajı
pencere.config(state='disabled')


yazı=Label(text='CHATBOT', fg="black", bg="red", font=('bold', 9))
yazı.pack()


mainloop()

asd = Text(root, bg='red', fg='white')
```

I'm doing bg red, but it's not working.

Comment: if you have short lines of text (which need only one line in Text) then you can count them and add empty lines at the beginning to move text to the bottom. But if text is longer and you don't use monospace font then you don't know how many lines it will use in Text.

Comment: you can assign tags to text and different tags may have assigned different colors for text and background. effbot.org: [Text](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm). Example: [tag colored text](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/tags)

Comment: to put widget in window use `pack()` or `grid()` or `place()`. Don't mix them. If you use `place()` then remove `pack()`

Comment: @furas thank you for your answer. My English is very bad :( Can you show me a sample code in my project? When insert text, I want to make background like speech bubble. asd = Text(root, bg='red', fg='white') but asd = ('deneme'), the 'deneme' background is not red. It's white. I just want the background to be red.

Comment: you have to use `tags` to set color - like in code in my link - `asd.tag_config('warning', background="red")` and later `asd.insert("deneme", tag="warning")`

Comment: @furas Sorry. I did it but gave the error. asd.insert("deneme", tag="warning")
TypeError: insert() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tag' **asd = Text(root)
asd.tag_config('warning', background="red")
asd.insert("deneme", tag="warning")**

Comment: see `insert()` in answer - there is correct version `insert('end', asd, 'bg_red')`

Comment: @furas I get it now. I'm grateful for your help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set color in `Text` you have to configure `tag` with color ('background', 'foreground')

```
 pencere.tag_config('bg_red', background='red')
```

and use this `tag` in `insert()`

```
  pencere.insert('end', asd, 'bg_red')
```

Minimal working example

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

pencere = Text(root)
pencere.pack()

pencere.tag_config('bg_red', background='red')
pencere.tag_config('bg_yellow', background='yellow')

pencere.config(state='normal')

asd  = 'deneme'

pencere.insert('end', '\nBOT:\t')
pencere.insert('end', asd, 'bg_red')

other_text = "hello"

pencere.insert('end', '\nUser:\t')
pencere.insert('end', other_text, 'bg_yellow')

pencere.config(state='disabled')

mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: I get it now. I'm grateful for your help. Thank you so much.